# Journey Builder - Date outArgument from custom activity failing in Decision Split activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Here is my scenario, I've created a custom journey builder activity that returns a date as one of its outArguments. Within the journey I've placed a Decision Split activity following my custom activity that uses the outArgument field as a part of the criteria for the split. However, whenever I run the query I either get the wrong outcome or the contact fails the decision split and is stuck in the activity.

- If Decision Split uses "equals" for comparison: Contact goes down remainder path even if dates are the same
- If Decision Split uses "after" for comparison: Contact fails split and stays in the activity

This only appears to happen for date arguments. Other data types seem to work just fine with the Decision Split activity. SFMC support has told me that the date format is invalid, but were unable to give me any further details on why it was failing. I then created a number of contacts each with varying date formats and still had no luck getting this to work.

**1. Has anyone accomplished what I'm trying to do?**

**2. What date format are you using?**

Comment: Are you sure that other outArguments data types work? If so, how are you defining setting these in your Decision Split Activity? I don't know if this has changed but from my experience, outArguments from Custom Activities can only be used by other Custom Activities, not by Standard Activities. I believe that you would need to create a custom split activity. I'm curious to find out how you are binding the outArgument to your Decision Split Activity...

Comment: @EliotHarper 99.9% they work. When you go to setup the Decision Split criteria you select Journey Data then it should show the outArgument options of the custom activity assuming the two are sequential on the canvas.

Comment: Oh, that must be new then. It certainly didn't used to be the case but good to know.

Comment: What is the format of the date you're returning as an out argument?

Comment: @Agoln I have literally taken the acceptable date format file from SFMC (the one that lists out each date format) and created contacts using those dates as a part of the journey entry data extension. Still had the same results.